# How To Write Snippet For Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

i am trying writing some useful snippets for me,i had already written some basics one in my `element.sublime-snippet`,but i found in [emmet-sublime](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) they have some snippet which multiply the elements.

```
eg : ul>li*3
Result:
     <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
     </ul>
```

how can i apply logics in my simple snippet `xml` code.

Comment: Actually I don't think these Emmet completions are implemented as simple snippets, so my guess is that you can't do this using snippets unless you write some custom plugin to do that ...

Comment: Read through the [Emmet customization docs](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/) to learn how to extend Emmet with your own completions.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Can you provide us with code example of your "simple snippet `xml`", and explain what does not work for you?